# como puedo obtener registros por semana de un mes?

Tags: html, mysql, sql

Tengo una base de datos de pedidos y debo obtener el numero de pedidos por semana, guiándome por el mes, o sea, pedidos de la primera semana, luego de la segunda, tercera, cuarta e incluso hasta la quinta semana del mes actual.
El punto es que no encuentro como obtener el numero de la semana ni como compararlo con la fecha que está en el pedido
solo he encontrado para obtener la semana actual según el mes pero no el resto de semanas

```
SELECT WEEK(curdate(), 5) - WEEK(DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(curdate()) - 1 DAY), 5)+1 as semana4;
```

esto es lo unico que he encontrado y me devuelve el numero de la semana actual del mes

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. Este tipo de preguntas, para que las respuestas sean bien efectivas y apropiadas, necesitan que incluyas datos de prueba, la definición de la tabla de la que tomas los registros y la salida esperada. Una consulta SQL sin contexto no dice mucho. :)

Comment: Si la respesta de felipe te ayudó, márcala como aceptada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si bien es cierto con esta funcion generas la semana actual:

```
select CONCAT(MONTHNAME(curdate()), ' semana ', FLOOR(((DAY(curdate()) - 1) / 7) + 1)) `mes`;
```

Podriamos usarla para hallar los registros por mes actual, no tengo tus valores de la tabla pero puedes reemplazar `created_at` por la columna donde tengas la fecha, y `count_sales` por la totalizacion que vas a sumar.

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(MONTHNAME(`created_at`), ' semana ', FLOOR(((DAY(`created_at`) - 1) / 7) + 1)) `mes`, 
  SUM(`count_sales`) AS `value`
FROM `ncr_letters`
GROUP BY 1 order by `mes`;
```