# Mi sql tiene un mal funcionamiento y no sé cómo arreglarlo, no sé por qué pasa esto

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una consulta en mysql en donde cuenta cuantos pedidos se hicieron en las semanas del mes actual, o sea deberia divirlo por 4, 5 o hasta semanas dependiendo del mes, el punto es que ahorita estaba haciendo unas pruebas y solo cuenta 3 semanas, incluso toma 2 semanas como 1 sola y no entiendo por qué

Metí datos en la primera, segunda, tercera y quinta semana y me traía los registros de la primera semana y la segunda semana en solo la primera semana, con la quinta semana, la traía como la tercera y con la tercera semana la traía como la segunda, este es el query

```
SELECT 
CONCAT( 'semana ', FLOOR(((DAY(`fecha_generado`) - 1) / MONTH(NOW())) + 1) ) `semana`,
count(*) AS `pedidos` 
FROM `pedido_online` 
WHERE MONTH(fecha_generado)=month(now()) 
and estado='confirmado' 
GROUP BY 1 order by `semana`;
```

Solo estoy trabajando sobre una tabla pero no entiendo por qué pasa esto. `estado='confirmado'`
hacer caso omiso ya que no afecta en lo que quiero hacer.
Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias.

Comment: El usuario que hizo esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/487697/como-puedo-obtener-registros-por-semana-de-un-mes) se llama igual que tu y tiene la misma duda.

Comment: Vale, no es exactamente la misma pregunta pero pues... al menos respóndele al que te dio respuesta en la pregunta anterior. ¿Por qué usas MONTH(NOW()) para dividir? Eso te va a dar 10 en octubre, 1 en enero, cosas así. Y dices que necesitas es el número de semanas

Comment: Y te copio/pego el comentario de tu anterior pregunta: no estás incluyendo algún dato de prueba y la salida esperada. No sabemos cómo creas tu tabla. Es más fácil recibir respuestas útiles cuando provees info suficiente para que te ayuden

Comment: Otro dato llamativo es que has hecho 8 preguntas y en ninguna has aceptado una respuesta.